# Add javascript code into the rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4.2

Actually, I'm having trouble adding javascript code into my rails application.

I tried putting the import.js in "app/assets/javascripts" as well and it didn't work either.

I also added,  //= require import at the end of application.js file but still not working.As a result the whole application got stucked.

index.html.erb

```
<a href="#">TEST</a>

<div id = "test">

    <h2>Import Statements</h2>

    <%= form_tag import_samples_path, multipart: true do %>
    <%= file_field_tag :file %>
    <%= submit_tag "Import" %>
    <% end %>

</div>
```

sample.coffee

```
# Place all the behaviors and hooks related to the matching controller here.
# All this logic will automatically be available in application.js.
# You can use CoffeeScript in this file: http://coffeescript.org/

    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $("div#test").hide();
        $("a").click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("div#test").toggle();
        });
    });
```

application.js

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or any plugin's vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require nicetitle
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things here:

First off - you need to have a `//= require_tree .` inside of your `application.js` file. What this does is automatically requires all of the files inside of your `javascripts` directory.

Next, (and I'm not *entirely* sure that this is best practice) the way that I call javascript inside of a `html.erb` file is inside of a `<script>` tag. I'll put an example of my code below. I only *very recently* figured out how to call JS from inside of html in rails, so like I said this is probably not best practice, but this is how I did it.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        var counts = ['Count']
        var dates = ['x']
        <% @chart.datasource.datapoints.each do |c| %>
          dates.push( "<%= c.date %>" )
          counts.push( <%= c.count %> )
        <% end %>
        chart(counts, dates);
</script>
```

So I actually put it inside of a script tag like you saw. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, it is working. What if I want to use in application.html.erb for most of the views?